# How do I create instances in class using user's input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, user-input

I am trying to create any number of instances in a class depending on the user's input but so far I unable to:

```
class CLASS_INVENTORY:
    maxcount_inventory = int(input("How many Inventories: "))
    for count_inventory in range(maxcount_inventory): 
        def __init__(Function_Inventory, inventory_name(count_inventory)):
            add_inventory = str(input("Enter Inventory #%d: " % (count_inventory+1)))
            inventory_name[count_inventory] = add_inventory
```

Note: I'm kind of new in Python 3 so I'm not sure if some of my syntax are right.

I want the output to be like this:

```
How many Inventories: 4
Enter Inventory #1: Fruits
Enter Inventory #2: Veggies
Enter Inventory #3: Drinks
Enter Inventory #4: Desserts
```

Here's my full code:
https://pastebin.com/3FBHgP6i
I'd also like to know the rules in writing Python 3 code if I'm following them right or I should change something. I'd like it to be readable as much as possible for other Python programmers.

Comment: Stepanjan's answer is accurate for the dynamically-sized array issue, but in terms of Python3 code rules, it is recommended to declare classes as: `class ClassName(object):`, where _object_ is the type that _ClassName_ sub-classes or implments (which may actually be _object_, in most cases). In general, it is also recommended to follow the [PEP8 guidance](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). This is easiest followed if you use a text-editor or IDE that supports PEP8 (e.g., Atom with some community plugins and pip packages).

Comment: Should i use an object here? May i ask your opinion to what i should name my object if i am to add one?

Comment: IMO, no. If the pastebin is your full code, then an array is wholly sufficient for your use-case. Some of the more _"OOP-everywhere"_ community members might disagree, since a class gives you the ability to extend and add data/fields later (e.g., maybe you will add a "Description" member to describe the type of content stored in the inventory), but as it stands right now, putting that in a class is overkill, in my opinion.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CLASS_INVENTORY():
    maxcount_inventory = int(input("How many Inventories: "))
    inventory=[]
    def __init__(self):
        for count_inventory in range(0, self.maxcount_inventory):
            add_inventory = str(input("Enter Inventory #%d: " % (count_inventory+1)))
            self.inventory.append(add_inventory)
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you included a small description of what you did differently. Otherwise the reader has to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.

Comment: i'd like to add that i need my inventory to be in order. Isn't dictionary and set both random (not in order)?

Comment: @Geni-sama, an array, which is what Stepanjan is suggesting, is ordered based on the order the user entered the items.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
# Define class
class CLASS_INVENTORY():
   # On making a class object init will be called
   def __init__(self):
       # It will ask for the inventory type count
       self.maxcount_inventory = int(input("How many Inventories: "))
       self.inventory = []
       # Just loop around it to get the desired result
       for count_inventory in range(0, self.maxcount_inventory):
           add_inventory = str(input("Enter Inventory #%d: " % (count_inventory+1)))
           self.inventory.append(add_inventory)
```

Output:

```
CLASS_INVENTORY()
How many Inventories: >? 2
Enter Inventory #1: >? Apple
Enter Inventory #2: >? Orange
```

Comment: are the added instances in order? aren't dictionaries and sets both random (not in order) when it comes to adding values?

Comment: I have used list thus, it will append in order. But if you use dictionary or set it will be random.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your *dicitonary* within `def _init__(self)` then set up a separate method `print_inventories` with a loop to `print` while maintaining the order of entry

```
class Inventory():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventories = {}
        n = int(input('How many inventories: '))
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            self.inventories[i] = input('Enter inventory #{}: '.format(i))

    def print_inventories(self):
        for k in self.inventories:
            print('#{}: {}'.format(k, self.inventories[k]))

a = Inventory()
a.print_inventories()
```

> ```
> How many inventories: 4
> Enter inventory #1: Fruits
> Enter inventory #2: Veggies
> Enter inventory #3: Drinks
> Enter inventory #4: Desserts
> #1: Fruits
> #2: Veggies
> #3: Drinks
> #4: Desserts
> ```